# Prove that a disk is convex in Tarski's geometry

Tags: geometry, axiomatic-geometry

Is it possible to prove that a disk is convex using only Tarski's axioms of geometry?

Specifically, I'm looking for a proof of:

$\forall a\,\forall b\,\forall c\,\forall d\,\forall e\,[ ab \equiv ac \land Badc \land Bbed \implies \exists f\,(ab \equiv af \land Baef)]$

Visually, this corresponds to the statement that $e$ lies within the disk.

[image]

I've been looking at [the axioms listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms), but I haven't figured out which of them implies that a disk is convex. Existing proofs of this and related problems seem to be mostly done using a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, which isn't available to me.

Comment: What does the capital letter $B$ stand for?

Comment: Also, you seem to expect this to follow from a single axiom. Do you have any reason for this expectation? A priori I can imagine a long complicated argument which employs most if not all of the axioms.

Comment: $B$ is the betweenness relation. $Babc$ if $b$ lies on the line segment from $a$ to $c$. I don't expect it to follow from a single axiom, but perhaps from one of the "complicated" ones such as Pasch plus the "simple" ones about reflexivity, transitivity, etc.

Comment: Let me suggest that you edit your post to include the information about $B$.

Comment: I took out my earlier comment about Pasch's axiom; I was thinking of the wrong axiom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Sorry I don't have time to explain the proof, but you can read it from our formal proofs. See the Lemma bet_inc2__incs in our formalization in Coq of foundations of geometry (https://github.com/GeoCoq/GeoCoq/blob/290642eff83097858f99084da9a149b021887473/Tarski_dev/Annexes/circles.v line 185) the main lemma used in this proof follows from results from chapter 5 of Mathematishe Methoden in der Geometrie.
( formalized in Coq here: https://github.com/GeoCoq/GeoCoq/blob/290642eff83097858f99084da9a149b021887473/Tarski_dev/Ch05_bet_le.v ).